# Specifying search type in google chrome before actual search begins

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

If I need to google foe news or image or anything other than web search, I need to open particular google site then I search or I enter text in chrome address bar which gives me web search result then I open particular google site to get desire result.

I want to get rid of this 2 step process.

Is there any add-on, extension, or chrome browser setting which can allow me to select search type before starting actual search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define search keywords by right-clicking a text input field on a website and selecting `Add As Search Engine...`.

Assuming you have added the keyword `gi` for Google's image search, you can type `gi kittens` in the address bar to instantly search for images of kittens.

---

If you want to delete a keyword you have defined like this, navigate to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`, hover over its entry in the list and click the `X`.